# Find first row that meets condition after each row's date, by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.frame` with 5 variables: **day** (Date, format: "YYYY-MM-DD"), **hour** (POSIXct, format: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"), **group** (chr), **measure_start** (numeric) and **measure_end** (numeric).

```
df <- structure(list(
  day = structure(c(18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116), class = "Date"), 
  hour = structure(c(1565275500, 1565276400, 1565277300, 1565278200, 1565279100, 1565280000, 1565280900, 1565281800, 1565282700, 1565275500, 1565276400, 1565277300, 1565278200, 1565279100, 1565280000, 1565280900, 1565281800, 1565282700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
  group = c("GROUP1", "GROUP1", "GROUP1", "GROUP1", "GROUP1", "GROUP1", "GROUP1", "GROUP1", "GROUP1", "GROUP2", "GROUP2", "GROUP2", "GROUP2", "GROUP2", "GROUP2", "GROUP2", "GROUP2", "GROUP2"), 
  measure_start = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 7, 15, 16, 32, 20, 21, 40, 15, 13, 22), 
  measure_end = c(3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8, 7, 16, 15, 31, 20, 21, 42, 15, 13, 26)),
  row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

For each row "i" of the `data.frame` I want to get the first row for which the condition "**measure_end** >= 2 * *measure_start_i*" is met; BUT ONLY for the hours of the day that are greater or equal to the hour of row "i", AND grouped by the same **day** and **group** of row the "i".

In other words, for each observation [*day_i, hour_i, group_i*, *measure_start_i*, *measure_end_i*] I want to get: which.min(**measure_end** >= 2 * *measure_start_i* | (**day** == *day_i*) *&* (**group** == *group_i*) *&* (**hour** >= *hour_i*)).

For instance, for the example above, the expected output should be:

```
          day                hour  group measure_start measure_end      row_with_me_2x_current_ms
1  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:45:00 GROUP1             2           3                              4
2  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:00:00 GROUP1             3           3                              6
3  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:15:00 GROUP1             3           3                              6
4  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:30:00 GROUP1             2           5                              4
5  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:45:00 GROUP1             4           4                              8
6  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:00:00 GROUP1             5           7                             NA
7  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:15:00 GROUP1             7           7                             NA
8  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:30:00 GROUP1             8           8                             NA
9  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:45:00 GROUP1             7           7                             NA
10 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:45:00 GROUP2            15          16                             12
11 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:00:00 GROUP2            16          15                             15
12 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:15:00 GROUP2            32          31                             NA
13 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:30:00 GROUP2            20          20                             15
14 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:45:00 GROUP2            21          21                             15
15 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:00:00 GROUP2            40          42                             NA
16 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:15:00 GROUP2            15          15                             NA
17 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:30:00 GROUP2            13          13                             18
18 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:45:00 GROUP2            22          26                             NA
```

My `data.frame` is pretty large, so I am guessing a `data.table` approach would probably work best. I am  still not very familiarized with the `data.table` syntax, though. My attempt below did not help much:

```
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,row_with_me_2x_current_ms:= which.min(dt[,measure_end] / measure_start >= 2) ,by=.(day,group)]
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: The expected output is shown above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to get the first index of logical vector.  We can group over 'day', 'group', then loop over the sequence of 'measure_start' with `lapply`, subset the value of 'measure_start' ('mst'), divide with the 'measure_end', get the index of the first row that meets the condition and assign it

```
library(data.table) 
dt[, row_with_me_2x_current_ms:= 
     unlist(lapply(seq_along(measure_start), function(i) {
        mst <- measure_start[i]
        i2 <- which((measure_end/mst) >=2)
        .I[i2[i2 >= i][1]]})),
   by = .(group, day)]
dt
#           day                hour  group measure_start measure_end row_with_me_2x_current_ms
# 1: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 09:45:00 GROUP1             2           3                         4
# 2: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:00:00 GROUP1             3           3                         6
# 3: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:15:00 GROUP1             3           3                         6
# 4: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:30:00 GROUP1             2           5                         4
# 5: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:45:00 GROUP1             4           4                         8
# 6: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:00:00 GROUP1             5           7                        NA
# 7: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:15:00 GROUP1             7           7                        NA
# 8: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:30:00 GROUP1             8           8                        NA
# 9: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:45:00 GROUP1             7           7                        NA
#10: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 09:45:00 GROUP2            15          16                        12
#11: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:00:00 GROUP2            16          15                        15
#12: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:15:00 GROUP2            32          31                        NA
#13: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:30:00 GROUP2            20          20                        15
#14: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:45:00 GROUP2            21          21                        15
#15: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:00:00 GROUP2            40          42                        NA
#16: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:15:00 GROUP2            15          15                        NA
#17: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:30:00 GROUP2            13          13                        18
#18: 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:45:00 GROUP2            22          26                        NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it is important that we find the first index where the condition is met for _each_ row (and not only the first one). Please see the expected output above.

Comment: @pabc May be your logic is not correct or the expected output..  I can't replicate those values in the expected output column

Comment: Hi @akrun. Sorry if my logic was not clear. The output column should return the first index of the rows, grouped under (day, group), for which the value in the column "measure_end" is at least twice the value of "measure_start". This calculation should be done for each row. For instance: for row 1, we have measure_start == 2. So the returned value should be "4", which is the first row for which measure_end >=2. For row 2, we have measure_start == 3, so the returned value should be "6", which is the first row for which measure_end >=3; and so on...

Comment: @pabc I was trying that logic.  Based on your code for the first row (not including the group here) `which((dt$measure_end[1]/dt$measure_start) >=2)#
integer(0)`

Comment: @pabc i.e. 3/5 = 0.6 and is not equal to >=2

Comment: The logic should be the opposite: `which((dt$measure_end/dt$measure_start[1]) >=2) #  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18`. So for this row, the code would return the first element: "4".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216794/discussion-between-pabc-and-akrun).

Comment: @pabc Is there another condition that I am missing for the row 17

Comment: Thanks, @ankur. That almost does it. But notice that your output is returning "the first row within the group" for which the criteria is met, and not "the first row within the group after or equal the current row" for which the criteria is met. Notice that we want `# NA NA 18 NA` for the last four rows, and your current suggestion returns `# NA 12 12 NA`

Comment: @pabc that was the confusion `after the current row`

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. This additional condition means that, for row 15, for example, we want to look only within rows {15, 16, 17 and 18} for the values in column **measure_end** that are at least twice those of **measure_start** (and not over the entire group).

Comment: In other words, we should limit our query (for the first row with "measure_end >= 2*measure_start") not only to our group, but also to rows with **hours** greater or equal the hour of each row.
For instance, row 17 should receive 18 because this is the first row below it that meets the condition.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option using non-equi join from `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, c("rn", "twice") := .(.I, 2 * measure_start)]

df[, row_with_me_2x_current_ms := 
    df[.SD, on=.(group, day, hour>=hour, measure_end>=twice), mult="first", rn]
]
```